# How to increase the session time in php

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

In my web application, when i try to hit authentication service by passing username and password. Following is the code that handles authentication.

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200"); // 120 minutes
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200"); // 120 minutes
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); /
$_SESSION['expire_time'] = 2*60*60; 
$_SESSION["user_id"]=$user_id;
$_SESSION["username"]=$username;
$_SESSION["accesslevel"]=10;
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
$proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$time = time();
header('Location: ../XXXX.php');
```

In above code I'm trying to establish 2hours of inactivity before `session_destroy();`. But when i check the cookie information in browser the expiry date is same as creation date.

> Help me in extending the cookie time to achieve system idleness.

[Image with the cookie inspector (Where it says `"Fecha de caducidad"` its the Expire date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRUJZ.png)

How to achieve this, guide me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These settings have no effect after the cookie is created (session initialized)

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
```

You have to check if session timed out:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > $_SESSION['expire_time'] )) { 
        session_destroy();
 } // check last activity
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // update last activity time
```

Comment: the ini_set parameters are set before the session_start();. I actually use the code you propose, but if the user does not refresh or click somewhere in the page for a short period of time the session ends automatically.